# jQuery addClass & removeClass

Tags: addclass, removeclass

I am very new in jQuery. I have 2 div with id="widget", by default there is a .active class to div1. I want remove this class when click on div2 and add .active class to div2.

There is my HTML:

```
<div class="progress_widget">

    <div id="widget" class="step1 active">
        <h1>1</h1>
        <h3>STEP 1 of 2</h3><h3 class="hide">Choose Heating System<br> for Estimate</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="step2" id="widget">
        <h1>2</h1>
        <h3>STEP 2 of 2</h3><h3 class="hide">Tell us How to Contact <br>You</h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

Please help me!!

Comment: What javascript have you tried so far?  This can be achieved with both javascript and jquery.  Please show your work related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can only have 1 unique ID per page

So I changed them to classes, like so

```
<div class="widget step1 active">
    <h1>1</h1>
    <h3>STEP 1 of 2</h3><h3 class="hide">Choose Heating System<br> for Estimate</h3>
</div>

<div class="step2 widget">
    <h1>2</h1>
    <h3>STEP 2 of 2</h3><h3 class="hide">Tell us How to Contact <br>You</h3>
</div>
```

and then for the jQuery, just do

```
$('.widget').click(function() {
    $('.widget').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

This jquery code will work for more than just 2 divs, so if you decide to add more elements with class widgets it will work with those too.

This is what the code does.
1. The user clicks on an element with the class widget
2. The jquery removes all classes of active from any elements with the class of widget
3. Then it adds the class of active to the one that was clicked on. `$(this)` just refers to the one that was clicked on.